# How to keep GCS key json file Safe?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, multer

When I used a bucket a key file was downloaded and it said keep this file safe ?
now I Cannot use .env to encrypt because in the following code you have to link the json file directly to gain access to GCS bucket.

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
keyFilename:path.join(__dirname,'/<keyfilename>.json'),
projectId:'<project ID>'
});
```

Now I am concerned when i deploy my app on the app engine this file may be accessed by someone somehow
that is a serious threat because it gives direct access to my GCS bucket

**Should I be concerned about that file being accessed by anyone??**

Comment: Do not use service account JSON key files on App Engine. Instead, use the service account assigned to App Engine and Application Default Credentials. In your code, remove **keyFilename** code and the storage client will automatically use the App Engine credentials. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/service-account

Comment: Key your secret safe? Don't have secrets!! Use ADC, and metadata servers and use the platform service account. *Note: recently you can customize the service account in app engine*

Comment: I am using Flexible env Will removing KeyFilename still Work?

Comment: Yes. App Engine Flexible has a default service account. Check that the permissions/roles that you require are assigned to the service account. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/default-service-account

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Service Account JSON file in AppEngine, You can use the App Engine default service. account to access the GCS buckets or any other service in GCP. By default, the App Engine default service account has the Editor role in the project, Any user account with sufficient permissions to deploy changes to the Cloud project can also run code with read/write access to all resources within that project. However, you can change the service account permissions through the Console.

- Open the Cloud Console.
- In the Members list, locate the ID of the App    Engine default
  service account.
  The App Engine default service account uses the member ID:
  ***YOUR_PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com***
- Use the dropdown menu to modify the roles assigned to the service
  account.